# JQuery Autocomplete Function Not Found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to implement JQuery's autocomplete function into an input field on a website. The inspector is giving me an error that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function.

I believe the problem might have to do with the order of my script tags but so far everything I have tried has not worked. Here is my content:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var schools = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#school").autocomplete ({
            minLength: 2,
            source: schools,
            select: function (e, ui) {
                e.target.value = ui.item.label;
                $("#schoolValue").val(ui.item.value);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How are you populating 'schools' variable with Tags for autocomplete? Not sure about the rest of the code but it looks like it might be blank.

Comment: Are there any error messages related to URLs not loading?

Answer (score 0):

On problem might be your jquery library, just for fun try changing it to

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

The order otherwise is right, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yqjca5gt/)

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means that jquery or jquery-ui hasn't yet been loaded. Check that your function call isn't getting hit before the document is loaded.

looks like you are using C#.
Just remove the `~` from the link and just the link from the root `/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and `Scripts/` it does not need to be uppercase. Usually in IIS, link URLs are not case sensitive.